# How to find the element text which are not visible on screen using pywinauto

Tags: python, automation, desktop, pywin32, pywinauto

I have a grid with horizontal and vertical scrolling and I want to print the complete data of this grid but I am unable to get as it is not visible onscreen.

Finding elements via scrolling doesn't provide a proper solution for the child elements. Any suggestion on how I can achieve this for the grid below?

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to create demo application with the same kind of grid? It would be extremely helpful to debug this problem.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov thanks for looking into it, but currently i don't have any demo application but if you want i can share the link from which it is created
https://www.grapecity.com/flexgrid

Comment: Thanks! I could find the demo. Unfortunately there is no any glue with `backend="uia"`. Just can reach the grid control itself, but no luck inside.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov thanks for looking into it, if there is any luck later please update this thread.